# Jupyter ipython clear_output() not working anymore

Tags: python, jupyter, ipython, ipywidgets

Working on Jupyter Version: 7.1.2.
This toy example does not work :

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

def page_1():
    button = widgets.Button(description="Next")
    def next_button_clicked(b):
        clear_output(wait=True)
        page_2()
    button.on_click(next_button_clicked)
    display(button)

def page_2():
    text = widgets.HTML(value='<h2 style="text-align:center">HELLO</h2>')
    display(text)

page_1()
```

page_1 does appear, but when clicking on the "Next" button, nothing happens. The "next_button_clicked" function is properly called, as indicated by additional prints (removed from the exposed example for brevity).

This example used to work properly before, and I suspect the problem appeared after a Jupyter upgrade.

Does somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With current ipywidgets in modern Jupyter tech, you need to specify how to handle where the `page_2()` content goes.
Here is a basic implementation that adjusts your code about as little as possible:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

out = widgets.Output()

def page_1():
    button = widgets.Button(description="Next")
    def next_button_clicked(b):
        clear_output(wait=True)
        page_2()
    button.on_click(next_button_clicked)
    display(button)

def page_2():
    with out:
        text = widgets.HTML(value='<h2 style="text-align:center">HELLO</h2>')
        display(text)


page_1()
out
```

That has been tested and run in Jupyter Notebook 7.1 and when pressing the button, the page 2 HTML is displayed in the center as directed.
You'll note that I have added `out` and using a context manager to wrap the directing of the content of page 2 to it.

Running your code in Jupyter Notebook 7.1, I see nothing happen when I press the button. **However, when running your code in JupyterLab, upon clicking the 'Next' button, I see the content of page 2 go to the Log Console.** (You can try this in a temporary JupyterLab session without needing to install anything on your computer, [by clicking here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/communication_voila/master?urlpath=%2Flab%2Ftree) to launch a session and then open a new notebook from the launcher panel. Ipywidgets is already installed there.)

That is symptomatic of ipywidgets output not being handled. See [an example here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-output-in-log-rather-than-cell/13419?u=fomightez) and [another here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/matplotlib-draw-in-console-instead-of-cell-output-when-call-in-widget-event-callback/22178?u=fomightez).

Because of this extra feedback you get when working with ipywidgets in JupyterLab, I suggest you are probably going to want to work in JupyterLab when troubleshooting ipywidgets. Jupyter Notebook is document-centric and doesn't expose the log console as far as I know.

Given the title about `clear_output()`, I was planning to add handling  transitions that involved that; however, before I could [the OP added a great example as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78185859/8508004). Those curious more about `clear_output()` and looking for additional related code can see [here and references therein](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/os-system-cls/9451/2?u=fomightez).

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. Adjusting your code, I could obtain what I expected :

Comment: (I'll put it in another answer, feel free to suggest improvements), sorry for the multi post...

Comment: That's great. Building on what I contributed to make  solution that addresses what you sought is more valuable than what I would have probably tried. I did test it in Voila and it indeed worked, too! [Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila#) let's you take Jupyter `.ipynb` file and run it without the code cells showing so it is more like an app rendering. It is meant to use ipywidgets.

Comment: It turns out that I was looking for a tool like Voila, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Wayne, I found a workaround, here is a working toy example :

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

out = widgets.Output()

def page_1():
    button = widgets.Button(description="Next")
    def next_button_clicked(b):
        with out:
            clear_output(wait=True)
        page_2()

    button.on_click(next_button_clicked)
    with out:
        display(button)

def page_2():
    text = widgets.HTML(value='<h2 style="text-align:center">HELLO</h2>')
    with out:
        display(text)

page_1()
out
```

Comment: Thanks for following-up and sharing this excellent example. I'm sure that will be useful to others who find this page when researching this.